# Download bootstrap navbar only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to use only the bootstrap navbar in my website without having to download all of the bootstrap code as it interferes with my current classes and divs.

Can anyone tell me which options to include in my custom download?

I clicked on navbar (it ticks other options which I assume are required for navbar to work) but my navbar won't work after including the css.

I have the Jquery and Bootstrap CDN links in my code so I'm pretty sure it's just the CSS.

Muchos thanks,

Comment: Please post your navbar code. thx.

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SkewerHed/84cSQ/). EDIT: It's the standard navbar code from the website. I wanted to make sure it works before changing it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay..... Problem solved!
Adrian missed just one selection (component animations).
... the nav bar in mobile was always open, rather than being 'click to open'.
Thanks though to Adrian for the starting point.

I did it the hard way.... trial and error.

To gain minimised script & css files, that allows the nav bar to work in both desktop, and mobile display formats...
... you need to check the following boxes:

**Common CSS**

- Grid System
- Forms
- Buttons
- Responsive Utilities

**Components**

- Navs
- Navbar

**Javascript Components**

- Dropdowns
- Component animations (for JS) (includes Collapse)

**JQuery Plugins**

- Dropdowns
- Collapse

Bingo!

Bloody marvelous!!!!!

Answer (score 10):

For a complete `navbar` like the image below,

*Normal*

[image: Bootstrap Navbar]
*Collapsed*

[image: Collapsed]

Go to this [link - getbootstrap.com/customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

Once there, uncheck all the checkboxes except for the following:

**Common CSS**

- Grid System
- Forms
- Buttons
- Responsive Utilities

**Components**

- Navs
- Navbar

**Javascript Components**

- Dropdowns

**jQuery Plugins**

- Dropdowns
- Collapse

Click the compile and download button at the bottom of the page.

Or just download the customize I made.

#### [Customized Bootstrap Download Link](https://minbox.com/app/collections/4sJAJqX/items/mcMckgQ)

#### [Offline Demo (Download First)](https://minbox.com/app/collections/4sJAJqX/items/HLWet45)

Comment: Based on your fiddle, it works but I think you should also include other components. Forms, navs, navbar,dropdown and basic utility.

Comment: The navbar in my fiddle doesn't toggle collapse on/off.

Comment: Hi there @SkewerHed, just to make sure that my answer is working, I tried it first. And please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap 4

If you're using Bootstrap 4, and couldn't find the "Bootstrap Customize", there's an alternative called [Bootstrap Theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

Here are the minimum required SCSS files to get Navbar to work:

```
 // Required (Must-have for any SCSS file(s) to work)
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
 
 // Bootstrap Navbar Styles
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot"; // Bootstrap Normalize (If you don't need normalization, delete it)
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid"; // You can get rid of it, the layout will get worse on Mobile, but you can fix it
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/nav";
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/navbar";
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/dropdown";
 @import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/transitions"; // When click on Mobile Button Menu Toggle, the menu gets collapse/uncollapse
```